# Display the Hindi encoded values in my select box

Tags: java, struts

I am working on struts framework in java and I have a jsp which has a select box. Onchange of this select box I am displaying some values in a second select box. The first select box is displaying the Hindi characters properly.   I select some value and the onchange function is called and it goes to ajax and gets the values in second select box. THe second select box is displaying question marks.The follwing is the jsp code

District(ज़िला)
                                                                
                                                            
                                                                
                                                                    
                                                                
                                                            
                                                            
                                                                Municipality(नगर)

```
                                                            <html:select property="municipalitycode" bundle="utf-8"
                                                                styleId="mun_List" style="width:180px;"
                                                                onchange="getzones('myajax.do?action=getzones',this);getsections('myajax.do?action=getsections',this);">
                                                                <html:option value="">Select</html:option>
                                                                <html:optionsCollection property="municipalities" />
                                                            </html:select>
                                                    </tr>
```

Onchange of district, I get muncipalities.
Please help?

Answer (score 1):

Character encoding can be quite tricky, make sure you haven't missed out on anything.
Refer the link below:
http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html

Comment: I have a select box which has some values in hindi. This select box is displaying the values in hindi properly but on change of this select box I am displaying some values in another select box which is displaying question marks

Comment: Did you refer to the link I posted?

Comment: @verve, I would advice you to edit your question with a code of what you're trying to do.